# .NET Security Policy change by standard users?

Tags: .net, windows, security

The .NET Security Policy can be changed from a script by using **CasPol.exe**. Say I will be distributing an application to several users on a local network. Most of those users will be unprivileged, standard accounts, so they will not have necessary permissions for the relevant command.

I think I shall be looking into domain logon scripts. Is there any alternative scenarios? Any solutions for networks without a domain?

Edit: I'm bound to use Framework version 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of .Net 3.5 SP1 now allows you to run managed executables over a network share without using CasPol.

See this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/08/13/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share.aspx)